# Find a bounded but non-constant solution of Poisson's equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, laplacian, partial-differential-equations

Consider Poisson's equation with homogenous Dirichlet boundary conditions
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
     \Delta u&=g \text{ in } B_R(0)\\  
 u&=0 \text{ on } \partial B_R(0),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $B_R(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a sphere around the origin with radius $R>0$.
Can we find an **explicit** example of a solution $u$ (and a corresponding function $g$) of this problem that is bounded but not constant? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just take any non-constant function $u$ that satisfies the boundary conditions and let $g=\Delta u$. If you want it to be explicit, you can take $u(x)=|x|^2-R^2$ and $g=2d$.